# Is there a program that allows me to see the hierarchy of PHP includes in a site?

Tags: php, include

I find myself having problems finding things in large include-rich websites that I have access to and need to edit.

I look at the php file I expect to find what I'm looking for in only to discover that it's made from several include files, and no sign of what im looking for. That's fine, I'll look in the includes -  until I go and look at those includes and discover that they are also comprised of several includes, and again further down the tree I go.

Is there a program that I can use to generate some sort of tree structure of the includes that make up a page?

Additionally, I'd love to have the facility to have some way to see the output of a PHP page that has pulled in whatever it is in the includes, but hasn't processed the PHP itself.

Comment: not sure if that is what you want but you can use [kcachegrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net) with [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/)

Comment: why can't you just to a workspace search in eclipse?

Comment: @locrizak - Should i assume from your response that Eclipse is a program that will do what I've asked?

Comment: Seems like a software design misunderstanding. A site consisting only of conglomerated includes and chaotic hierarchies are not part of this century anymore. Get a decent IDE (PhpStorm, Eclipse) and a good framework (maybe based on `MVC`) and don't let such problems bother you.

Comment: I've had these problems trying to find things in Wordpress and Interspire Shopping Cart. I'm fairly new to PHP but a lot of the time I know what I'm looking for, but I struggle to find it to work with it.

Comment: @RichardDownes Yeah wordpress is a giant mess! But it justifies itself with doing its job, and thats it. But if you just started then my suggestions would be too much. Try to find the way out of the jungle with help of Google. You seem to be interested and curious yourself, so you *will* get it with the help of the internet :)

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about the tree of includes (without writing code to scan the source files) but you can use the [get_included_files](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-included-files.php) function to get a list of all included files.

Comment: Thank you, I had a look and while I don't get the tree structure, I at least get to see all the files that are called. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

PHP isn't like Java where all the includes are done separately from the execution; 'include' is itself a function that is called during the execution of the code, which renders this impossible.

To be honest, even if you could do this, I'm not convinced it would help you find what you're looking for. In general the best way to find things is either to understand the directory structure of the site or use an IDE (Eclipse, Netbeans, etc) or text editor (NotePad++, etc.) that allows you to search all files in a directory and its subdirectories.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong in my understanding how an include works within PHP..

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong in my understanding how an include works within PHP, I was under the impression that within a php file containing an include, the contents of the include were pulled in as they were called then executed before moving onto whatever was after it. If that was the case, I'm not sure why it wouldn't be possible to have some way to see a page that contained the potential output of includes in the original, perhaps highlighted, prior to being executed for the browser?

Comment: @RichardDownes technically I suppose you could have something that executed the php while creating a copy of the file in which any includes are replaced by the included code, but it still wouldn't be able to handle includes that are called more than once. More importantly the output would be so long and unwieldy as to be completely useless.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-print-backtrace.php

Answer (score 0):

Using the advanced functionnalities of [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/docs/) (php extension) you can achieve that and even more

More specifically `Function Traces` which display every function calls as well as the file in which the function is, so from that, you could get a list of all included files.

Kind of old link but most still applies http://devzone.zend.com/1139/profiling-php-applications-with-xdebug/